# Even and Odd boxes

Tags: python

Basically the program I have to write makes it so that even numbers made solid squares while odd numbers make outlined squares. So far I've managed to set it up so that even numbers work just fine. However, odd numbered squares are missing * and aren't spaced apart from one another.

```
#Input

box_size=int(input("Enter square size:"))

if (box_size % 2) == 0:
    box_size=int(box_size)
    for row in range(box_size,0,-1):
        for col in range(row):
            print('*'*row*2,end='')
            print()
        print()

else:
    inner_size = box_size - 2
    print ('*' * box_size)
    for i in range(inner_size,0,-1):
        print ('*' + ' ' * inner_size + '*')
        print ('*' * box_size)
    print()

#Output for even

Enter square size:6
************
************
************
************
************
************

**********
**********
**********
**********
**********

********
********
********
********

******
******
******

****
****

**

#Output for odd

Enter square size:5
*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****
*   *
*****

#The odd output seems to be missing some * 
#and there's no spaces between them. Each box is 
#supposed be smaller than the last till it reaches zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the bottom of the box *inside* the loop -- on every iteration:

```
for i in range(inner_size,0,-1):
    print ('*' + ' ' * inner_size + '*')
    print ('*' * box_size)
print()
```

Instead, do it only when you're entirely finished with the inner box:

```
for i in range(inner_size,0,-1):
    print ('*' + ' ' * inner_size + '*')

print ('*' * box_size)
print()
```

This will get you one box; you've already figured out how to step down the size, where you do the even-sided ones